# JavaScript ES6 instantiating with dependency injection classes which depend on each other

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, es6-class

Still trying to get the hang of dependency injection, I've run into a problem.  I have three classes: Main, Store, Model.  Store does as the name suggests: stores data which is accessible elsewhere.  Model retrieves data from the DB, in my case local/Chrome storage.  I'm trying to write the classes in a decoupled way so I can test/modify it later.  But of course, I keep getting `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error because I think Store and Model just keep going round and round...circular dependancy.  What's a possible solution?

```
store.js
export class Store { //ok there's also a config class but that's not the problem
    constructor(config, model) {
        this._config = config;
        this._model = model;
    }
//...
}


model.js
export class Model {
    constructor(config, store) {
        this._config = config;
        this._store = store;
    } 
//...
}


main.js
import { Store } from './store.js'
import { Config } from './config.js'
import { Model } from './model.js'

export class Main {
    constructor(config, store, model) {
        this._store = store;
        this._model = model;
    }
//...
}
const config = new Config();
const model = new Model(config, ???);
const store = new Store(config, ???);
const main = new Main(config, model, store);
```

Is there a fix, workaround, anything?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Assign the `model` or `store` *after* instantiation? Eg `store.setModel` or something (only called once)?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't throw a stack overflow. What are you actually doing? Are you calling any methods from inside your constructors?

Comment: In the last part of `main.js`, I need to inject `store` into the Model constructor and `model` into the Store contructor.  Functions inside both classes talk to each other, eg when some value gets set in the Store, a function gets called in the Model to save the data.  And vice versa.  So I need them to be dependent on each other yet...decoupled when I want to test each separately.  Does that make any sense?

Comment: Well, you've designed them so they can't be decoupled as the constructor for each depends on the other.  There is no independence by your own design.  Either break the dependency that so each object can be constructed truly independently or put them in the same file so they can circularly reference each other without problem and be dependent upon each other.  If you want to test them independently, you have to truly make them independent of each other.

Comment: Yeah...I see that.  Stupid question really.  Best solution: Store class shouldn't be dependent on the Model?